# Restore inaccessible folder

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7-x64

I have mess up a folder and now it is inaccessible. If I do a "Dir" the folder is not shown. If I try to create a folder with the same name, I get an error that the file or folder noes not exists.
How is it possible for me to access the folder again?

Answer (score 0):

**Try a chkdsk at next boot.**
So, open the Command Prompt window, for noobs:

```
Window+r and cmd+Enter
```

Copy and paste the following commands in the cmd window :

```
chkdsk /x /f /r
Y
```

Reboot and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
It is solved now. I had our Domain Admin to fix it for me. He could take ownership of the folder and do magic trix.